# Extracting start and end date in groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL Server table were each row represent a machine log that says the time when the machine were switched on or switched off. The columns are ACTION, MACHINE_NAME, TIME_STAMP

ACTION is a String that can be "ON" or "OFF"
MACHINE_NAME is a String representing the machine id
TIME_STAMP is a date.

An example:

```
ACTION        MACHINE_NAME          TIME_STAMP
ON            PC1                   2016/03/04 17:13:10
OFF           PC1                   2016/03/04 17:13:15 
ON            PC1                   2016/03/04 17:14:15 
OFF           PC1                   2016/03/04 17:15:45
```

I need to extract from these logs a new table that can tell me: "The machine X was ON for N minutes from START_TIME to END_TIME"

How could I write an SQL Query in order to do this?

Desired result

```
MACHINE_NAME          START_TIME                    END_TIME
PC1                   2016/03/04 17:13:10           2016/03/04 17:13:15
PC1                   2016/03/04 17:14:15           2016/03/04 17:15:45
```

Comment: MySQL != MS SQL Server

Comment: I don't have too much experience with these kind of queries. I'm stuck because I don't know how to properly aggregate "ON" and "OFF" status from two different rows into a single one

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Will there ever be unmatched data and how do you wish to deal with these (not just, it's currently ON and hasn't turned OFF yet, but possibly spurious sequences like ON, ON, OFF or ON, OFF, OFF)?

Comment: yes there is that possibility and in that case no entry should be inserted in the result

Comment: @LucaS. I don't thing anyone who answered before was aware of the risk that there is unmatched data. I added a new answer that takes this into consideration, and it passed all my test cases so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this using CTEs and the `LAG` function. This enables us to get the first `'ON'` action for each `'OFF'`, and thereafter apply `ROW_NUMBER` to match them:

```
;WITH first_ON AS 
(
    SELECT *, LAG(m.ACTION, 1, 'OFF') OVER (PARTITION BY m.MACHINE_NAME ORDER BY m.TIME_STAMP) AS previous_action
    FROM your_table m
), 
ON_actions AS
(
    SELECT
            m.ACTION,
            m.MACHINE_NAME,
            m.TIME_STAMP,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY TIME_STAMP ) AS RN
    FROM first_ON m
    WHERE m.previous_action = 'OFF' AND m.ACTION = 'ON'
), 
OFF_actions AS (
    SELECT 
            m.ACTION,
            m.MACHINE_NAME,
            m.TIME_STAMP,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY TIME_STAMP ) AS RN
    FROM your_table m
    WHERE m.ACTION = 'OFF'
)

SELECT a.MACHINE_NAME, a.TIME_STAMP AS START_TIME, b.TIME_STAMP AS END_TIME
FROM ON_actions a
INNER JOIN OFF_actions b ON a.MACHINE_NAME = b.MACHINE_NAME AND a.RN = b.RN
```

EDIT: This solution also takes unmatched ONs and OFFs into consideration, for example ON,ON,OFF,ON,ON,ON,OFF,OFF.

Comment: How is ON ON OFF even possible? how can you turn on a machine, then turn it on again before you shut it down?

Comment: Again, see comment below the question from Damien_The_Unbeliever. He asked if that can happen, and Luca S. clearly said yes aswell as how this should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a correlated query like this:

```
SELECT t.Machine_name,
       t.time_stamp as start_date,
       (SELECT min(s.time_stamp) from YourTable s
        WHERE t.Machine_name = s.Machine_Name
          and s.ACTION = 'OFF'
          and s.time_stamp > t.time_stamp) as end_date
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.action = 'ON'
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.Machine_name,
           t.time_stamp as start_date,
           (SELECT min(s.time_stamp) from YourTable s
            WHERE t.Machine_name = s.Machine_Name
              and s.ACTION = 'OFF'
              and s.time_stamp > t.time_stamp) as end_date
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE t.action = 'ON')
WHERE end_date is not null
```

Comment: This returns 4 rows instead of 2.

Comment: @DNac Correct, fixed.

Comment: What does it return then? And BTW, no need to downvote for a typo.

Comment: @DNac for the data provided, it does.

Comment: He just downvoted me because he thinks I downvoted him. @tobypls

Comment: @sagi please, dont be silly .. that's not case .. it was because it did not return the correct data, so calm down.

Comment: It is correct now, so whats the excuse? And its never a good reason to downvote an answer for a typo, only for wrong answer @DNac ..

Comment: It works like a charm!! Thanks a lot! How can I edit this to filter results where end_date is empty? This happens sometimes when an "OFF" status is not recorded.

Comment: This doesn't take unmatched ONs and OFFs into consideration. Sequences such as ON, ON, OFF, OFF

Comment: @tobypls Because logicly this is not possible, how can you turn on a machine, and turn it on again before you turned it off?

Comment: @sagi See comments below question (from Damien_The_Unbeliever)

Comment: @LucaS. do you have any input in this? Does it in fact manage cases where the ONs and OFFs come unordered?

Comment: an OFF log can be missing after an ON log (when the machine crashes instead of shutdown properly for example). It cannot happen that the machine shutdown twice in a row (OFF , OFF case)

Comment: @LucaS. And how should that be handled? This solution just seems to add rows for each ON. Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Give a row_number based on `time_stamp` and `machine_name` and then a `group_id`.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select rn = row_number() over(      
        order by time_stamp, machine_name
    ), *
    from your_table_name
)
select z.machine_name, z.start_time,
case when z.start_time = z.end_time then null 
    else z.end_time end as end_time from(
        select t.machine_name, min(t.time_stamp) as start_time, 
        max(t.time_stamp) as end_time from(
            select ((rn - 1) / 2) + 1 AS Group_Id, * 
            from cte
     )t
     group by t.machine_name, t.Group_Id
)z;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner joining the table to itself will produce the desired output and is fairly simple to write in SQL Server. I use this type of format fairly often where I work.

```
SELECT m1.MACHINE_NAME, m1.TIME_STAMP AS START_TIME, MIN(m2.TIME_STAMP) AS END_TIME
FROM MACHINE_LOG m1
INNER JOIN MACHINE_LOG m2 ON m1.MACHINE_NAME = m2.MACHINE_NAME
    AND m2.ACTION = 'OFF'
    AND m2.TIME_STAMP > m1.TIME_STAMP
WHERE m1.ACTION = 'ON'
GROUP BY m1.MACHINE_NAME, m1.START_TIME
```